# verifying arima coefficients

Tags: r

I use the following sample code, to run AR1 process on data
 (just numbers I picked to check the function):

```
> data
[1] 3 7 4 6 2 8 5 4
> data_ts
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 3 7 4 6 2 8 5 4
> arima(data_ts,order=c(1,0,0))

Call:
arima(x = data_ts, order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
          ar1  intercept
      -0.6965     5.0323
s.e.   0.2334     0.2947

sigma^2 estimated as 1.769:  log likelihood = -13.97,  aic = 33.93
```

residuals are:

```
> arima(data_ts,order=c(1,0,0))$resid
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -1.4581973  0.5521706  0.3383218  0.2487084 -2.3582160  0.8556328  2.0348596
[8] -1.0547538
```

Now, the coefficient should be -0.6965 and the intercept 5.0323. I'd like to verify the result. So I'm assigning the parameters accordingly i.e.:

```
data[8] = intercept + coefficcient_data[7] + residual[8]
```

but it never gets correct. What am I doing wrong? BTW - trying the ar function produces different results:

```
ar(x = data_ts, aic = FALSE, order.max = 1, method = "ols")

Coefficients:
      1  
-0.6786  

Intercept: 0.3527 (0.4951)
```

Order selected 1  sigma^2 estimated as  1.709. And still - when I assign the time-series parameters onto the estimated equation + errors, the result isn't correct. Any idea ?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the answer in http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm
the actual intercept is:   intercept*(1- coefficient)